# Arista eos eAPI for full config

Tags: networking, arista

Anyone worked on full configuration of arista switches using the eAPI? I am going through the ansible eos_ modules and see that there are few missing configs. Do we have to use eos_config module for anything that is missing. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arista EOS modules are still being added with every new Ansible release, but you're correct that there are some things that aren't possible with the current set of modules yet. `eos_config` is the way we've solved that (and more, since we started writing Ansible modules before a number of modules were available).